# Julia | How to access nested key in a json file

Tags: json, julia

I have the contacts.json file:

```html
{
  "emergencyContacts": [
    {
      "name": "Jane Doe",
      "phone": "888-555-1212",
      "relationship": "spouse"
    },
    {
      "name": "Justin Doe",
      "phone": "877-123-1212",
      "relationship": "parent"
    }
  ]
}
```

So I wanna access Name key in emergencyContacts array in Julia. I'm trying this:

```html
import JSON
dict = Dict()
open("contacts.json", "r") do f
    global dict
    dicttxt = readstring(f)  # file information to string
    dict=JSON.parse(dicttxt)  # parse and transform data
end
for (values) in dict["emergencyContacts"]
         println(values)
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a poorly specified question:

1. There is no "firstname" key.
2. There is no "Employees" array.

Presumably, you are looking for

```
julia> first_names = String[]
0-element Array{String,1}

julia> for contact in dict["emergencyContacts"]
           push!(first_names, split(contact["name"]," ")[1])
       end

julia> first_names
2-element Array{String,1}:
 "Jane"  
 "Justin"
```

The "nested" key called "name" can be extracted for an array element using `dict["emergencyContacts"][n]["name"]` where `n` is array index.